# How to Create Sitemap file in .netcore 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-core-6.0

I tried to create SiteMap.xml file. In localhost code working perfecty and creating the file, but after hosting on server it will showing 500 error and does not creating Sitemap file

```
var list = new List<SitemapNode>();
foreach (var item in listdata)
{
  double? priority = 1;
  if (item.Priority != 0 && item.Priority != null) { priority = item.Priority; }
  list.Add(new SitemapNode { LastModified = item.ModifiedOn, Priority = priority, Url = item.Link });
}
new SitemapDocument().CreateSitemapXML(list, Environment.WebRootPath);
```

and also included this in Program.cs file before app.UseRouting()

```
app.UseXMLSitemap(environment.WebRootPath);
```

When this code hosted, in browser console it will show 500 error. But in local host its working fine. This line causing the 500 error on server "new SitemapDocument().CreateSitemapXML(list, Environment.WebRootPath);" When i'm removing this line from hosted file no error comes but with this line error comes.

I have done everything but still not working.

ScreenShot link of Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRs8V.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you're getting a HTTP 500 status then it most likely means something in your code is throwing an unhandled exception. Try wrapping the whole method in a `try { .... } catch (Exception ex) { ... }`, and in the `catch` block, [log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) the details of the exception. If you can add the exception type, message and stack trace to your question then we'll be in a much better position to help.

Comment: When this code is hosted. after that in browser console it will show 500 error. But in local host its working fine. This line causing the 500 error on server "new SitemapDocument().CreateSitemapXML(list, Environment.WebRootPath);"  When i'm removing this line from server no error comes but this line error comes.

Answer (score -1):

This is working sample

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _env = env;
        }

        //not returning any view  
        public string CreateSitemapInRootDirectory()
        {
            var list = new List<SitemapNode>();
            list.Add(new SitemapNode { LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow, Priority = 0.8, Url = "https://www.example.com/asp-dot-net-turotial-part1", Frequency = SitemapFrequency.Daily });
            list.Add(new SitemapNode { LastModified = DateTime.UtcNow, Priority = 0.7, Url = "https://www.example.com/asp-dot-net-turotial-part3", Frequency = SitemapFrequency.Monthly });
            new SitemapDocument().CreateSitemapXML(list, _env.WebRootPath);
            return "sitemap.xml file successfully created";
        }
     }
```

program.cs

```
app.UseXMLSitemap(builder.Environment.WebRootPath);
```

IIS test.
[image]

I think there should be something wrong to inject in enviroment service.
Another thing you could try is adding `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` to see detail error page when host in IIS.

Comment: What you said I have do that all but after Hosting the file on server still getting the 500 error. I have added the Screen Shot in Question

Comment: @AnkitaSen what is your IIS version. Try reinstall .net6 hosting bundle.